# How to assign posted values to a variable in cakephp?

Tags: php, post, cakephp-2.0

I likes to assign posted values to a variable,
In view i wrote the code,

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Register'); ?>
<fieldset>
    <?php echo $this->Form->input('username');
    echo $this->Form->input('password');
    echo $this->Form->input('Confirm password');
?>
</fieldset>
```

Form->end(__('Submit'));

and in controller,

```
if($this->request->is('post')){
    //print_r($this->data);
    $uname = $this->request->data('username');
    echo "uname".$uname;
    exit;
}
```

The problem is that i didnt get the value on $uname.

Comment: what is the result of this print_r($this->data);?

Comment: variable $uname is null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your debug is enabled. Use this - `pr($this->request->data);` to see what's in that variable. The CakePHP form naming data usually looks something like this

```
$this->request->data['Formname']['fieldname']
```

In your case it should be

```
$this->request->data['Register']['username']
```

Answer (score 0):

please try using this code

```
$this->params['form']['YOUR_VARIABLE_NAME']
```

or

```
$this->data['FORMNAME']['YOUR_VARIABLE_NAME']
```